# React js внедрение своих плагинов

Tags: reactjs

Перехожу на React и столкнулся с проблемой - как внедрить собственные скрипты и плагины для взаимодействия с DOM.

Я в курсе, что есть много готовых решений конкретно под React но все же, мне интересно, как вообще можно подружить React и моими плагинами.

Возьмем для примера плагин, который делает анимацию инпута при фокусе, наборе текста и т.д.

https://github.com/Deathdrummer/test/blob/master/public/js/assets/plugins/input.js

Или тут весь смысл в том, что теперь эти плагины мне в принципе уже не понадобятся и нужно кардинально переписывать все скрипты и плагины под React.

Просветите пожалуйста, кто знает.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но мне не совсем понятно то, как изложено в данной документации и примеров конкретных нет